# Understanding app engine deployment model

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Being very new to googles app engine, i have used Intellij IDEA plugins to deploy my REST java app. Having that passed smoothly, together with my app ive got two compute engine virtual machines. What are they for? Why two and how does they select required VMs configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the App Engine flexible environment AND that you're using the older version of it rather than the new beta version. The older version has `vm: true` in your `app.yaml` file. The newer version, which was just announced on Nov 15, 2016, uses `env: flex` in the `app.yaml` file.

The flexible environment runs on top of Compute Engine virtual machines. In the older version these your app's instances would show up under Compute Engine. With the newer version these now display in the console on the [App Engine instances page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/instances).

You're going to want to look into [migrating your app to the new version of the flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/upgrading) before the old beta version is deprecated at some point in the next year. If you used on the "compat" runtimes from before, you might check to see if you really need to use the flexible environment or does the standard environment support your app's needs? Depending on your app, one environment might be cheaper than the other.

All that said, you can configure the underlying virtual machines in the flexible environment by using the `app.yaml` file. See the [resource settings in the `app.yaml` reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings) for details. Later, if you needed to debug your code on the instances, see [Debugging an instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/debugging-an-instance).

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the reason. Unfortunately Intellij IDEA does not support app.yaml without Dockerfile, therefore added sample Dockerfile and it seem worked. One problem though, my application from myapp.appspot.com now redirects to 1-dot-myapp.appspot-preview.com and does not seem to record any traffic... Any idea?